# Always coloring output of grep command

Tags: linux, grep

I almost exclusively use grep with -nr options and --color

Can I set something in my linux environment to use it by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your ~/.bashrc:

```
alias grep='grep -nr --color'
```

and source your ~/.bashrc or login with a second shell:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```